# raise TypeError("expected non-empty vector for x") TypeError: expected non-empty vector for x

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, ros

I have a project which is OpenCV python lane dedection, i can easily run code with video(importing VideoFileClip in moviepy.editor). Actually when i try to convert video file to real time using VideoCapture. I can get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "advanced_lane_finding(1).py", line 619, in <module>
    a=process(frame)
  File "advanced_lane_finding(1).py", line 575, in process
    left_poly = fit_poly(binary,llo, lhi, process.old_left_points)
  File "advanced_lane_finding(1).py", line 462, in fit_poly
    poly = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(pts[0],pts[1],2))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in polyfit
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 601, in polyfit
    raise TypeError("expected non-empty vector for x")
TypeError: expected non-empty vector for x
```

I want to run with my webcam my code

Comment: No one will really be able to answer this without seeing your code.

Comment: please share the code snippet you are getting this error

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk  
I try to use this code for the project which [link](https://github.com/windowsub0406/Advanced-lane-finding ) I tried to run with webcam. But couldn't run.

Comment: I try to use this code for the project which [link](https://github.com/windowsub0406/Advanced-lane-finding ) I tried to run with webcam. But couldn't run. @BTables